# SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-windows Command not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have installed SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-windows on my windows Xp 32-bit.
following is the command I am running on command prompt.

```
C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3>sencha app create MyApp c:\xampp\htdocs\sencha\myapp\
```

Giving following error

> [ERROR] the current workind directory (C:\Program
>   Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3>) is not valid SDK directory. Please
>   'cd' in to a SDK directory before executing this command.

environment variable has been set following way.

Variable name : Path
Value : C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3

can anyone figure out what exactly wrong in this process ?

Comment: I followed solustion in this link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re)
It works great.
Basically, install sencha command 3.0 in bin folder of sdk tools.

Answer (score 2):

********Sencha Touch setup Guide steps(in Window)*********

1. Download Sencha Touch SDK Tool. (http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/ -->SDK Tools Beta for Developers). Run .exe file. It will install tool to default path. (i.e. C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3)
2. Download Sencha Touch SDK. (Download openSource version file licensed under GPL.).
3. Extract SDK you just download in step 2.
4. Open Command line terminal (start->Run->type cmd). Change directory path to SDK path as you just extracted in step3.
5. Verify that Sencha Command is working properly on your machine. So Type Sencha.
   E.g. sdkPath>sencha

   - you will see "Sencha Command v2.0.2" message with other sencha command detail.
6. Create app in your web directory by typing following.
   E.g. sdkpath> sencha app create firstSenchaApp "path/ to/ www"

   (If you have tomcat 7 installed in your computer, give path to \apache-tomcat-7.0.30-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\webapps)
   Note: There must not be space in directory path name. _(underscore),- (desk)  are allowed.
7. If app is not generated in step 6. There might be an error. There are as follow:

   - If error message appear is "sencha' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”, follow these steps to troubleshoot:
     The path to SDK Tools directory is prepended to your system's PATH environment variable.
     From the terminal, run
     echo $PATH or echo %PATH% .

     The SDK Tools directory should be displayed in part of the output. If this is not the case, add it to your PATH manually.
     The environment variable SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_{version} is set, with the value being the absolute path to the installation directory mentioned above.
     For example: If the installed version is '2.0.0-beta2', a SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 must be set.
     From the terminal, run
     echo $SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 or echo %SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2% on Windows.

   If the output is empty, set the environment variable manually.

   - Wrong Current Working Directory
   - A common mistake is not running Sencha Command within either a valid SDK directory or an application directory. If the current directory is not    a SDK or application directory, "sencha" command will fallback to backwards-compatible mode. As of SDK Tools release "2.0.0-beta2", you should see  a clear warning in such case:
     "The current working directory (...) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards compatible mode."   So in this case follow proper step as mentioned above.
     Reference:
     http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192169-Important-SDK-Tools-Sencha-Command-Update

Answer (score 0):

There is an invisible file that you need to copy, called `.senchasdk`.  Make sure it is in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having the same problem I had; I had attempted to run 'sencha app create...' from the folder containing sencha.bat.  Instead, you need to run 'sencha app create...' from the sencha-touch-2.0.1.1 folder (which contains the .senchasdk file).

Answer (score 0):

See [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re?lq=1)!
Save my days.

By the way, if you can't extract the sencha-cmd to sdk tools, try to extract on other location and copy the folder [3.0.0.250] to your sdk tools > [bin] folder.
hope this helps.