# [WARN] The current working directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha folder) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder.

Tags: sdk, command, xampp, extjs

I'm new in Sencha . but after installation.. it's really becoming a headache..

I dont' know how to resolve this issue..
I downloaded -

- sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial - (its SDK i think)
- SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-windows (These are Tools for SDK)
- Xampp (for Web services)
- I installed xampp.
- extracted sencha touch into htdocs folder under xampp.
- installed senchSDKTools

  And started applying commands from CMD
- i typed sencha and pressed enter...
- but i get following error.

-

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial>sencha
[WARN] The current working directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercia
l) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards comp
atible mode.

    Sencha Command v2.0.0 Beta 3
Copyright (c) 2012 Sencha Inc.
usage: sencha COMMAND [ARGS]

The available commands are:
   build                        build a JSB project
   create bootstrapdata         generate boostrap data
   create jsb                   generate a minimal JSB project for an app
   create locale                        generate a template locale file from sourc
e
   create manifest              generate classes manifest
   package                      package your Touch web app into a native bundle
   slice theme                  slice a custom theme's images for IE

See 'sencha help COMMAND' for more information on a specific command.

C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial>
```

-I've searched several website.. but couldn't get the solution..
Please help me.. thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Problem:** Sencha SDK could not be recognized through `cmd`

**Error:**

> [warn] the current working directory (c:\xampp\htdocs\sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial) is not a recognized sencha sdk or application folder. running in backwards compatible mode.

**Issue:** The problem arises because of outdated cmd that Sencha use for creating, updating, packaging apps. Check the above command when entering `sencha` and it showing currently installed cmd version is:

```
sencha command v2.0.0 beta 3
```

**Solution :** Sencha command has been updated to v3.0.0 with more features like "generating" commands which was not supported in v2.0.0. Just download it from below link and install it (in the bin folder of SDK tools, not touch SDK). That's it. Now go to the Sencha touch folder and again  through it run `sencha`. What will you get now is:

```
sencha cmd v3.0.0.250
```

You can also fire this command

```
$ sencha generate app gs ../gs
```

And it work too!

**Note:** Sencha didn't say that you needed to update Sencha cmd, but updated their documentation. Numerous people are facing this Sencha problem with no luck. Hope people get rid of it which took a complete night from me :)

Comment: About `DOWNLOAD IT FROM BELOW LINK`. You forget to provide link to install it.

Comment: great! really why it is not mentioned in the documents... thx a lot!

Comment: that was a mistake & regretting for it.

Comment: I'd like to add that you must uninstall and delete the Sencha folder from `X:\Users\**Username**\bin\Sencha` where X is your drive and Username is your username.

Comment: Hi I am on IIS. And I want to know how and where I should extract the Sencha touch to.

Answer (score 10):

I faced same Error on Windows. So I uninstall Current SDK Tool version 2.0  and install new sdk tool ( version 3.0 ) . It is working fine.

download link for new version.
http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Comment: Thanks man.. for both of you .. cleansafi and thanumoorthy.. for making me understand

Answer (score 4):

Follow just following steps:-

1. Download latest Sencha SDK
   http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/
2. Download latest Sencha Command line
   http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download
3. Install Sencha Command line default location in Windows is
   C:\Users\XXX\bin
4. After CMD Installation go to SDK folder install/extract in Step 1
5. Run following command (I am running this command using GIT Bash
   on windows)

   /c/Users/SMAK/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250/sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp

**Note:-
We need both Sencha SDK and CMD and you have to run Command from SDK Folder**

Comment: thank the maker ! that worked. So far i was pulling my hairs out trying to use the SDK tools (which are absolute crap, because they use no registry information but for their install location). :D thank youuuu ! :D

Comment: I was having this issue on osx. One thing I would add is make sure you close your terminal sessions. Sometimes the path doesn't update and you run into the same error.

Also if you have the 2.x tool install use the uninstaller before installing the CMD tool.

Comment: I am on IIS. IIS works on all my .net projects. I even added the json to MMIM. I have gotten everything installed. **But I am not sure where to extract the touch-2.4.0.zip file.** can you let me know where?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Sencha Cmd. I solved this problem by uninstalling the "SenchaSDKTools".

As for me it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message. 
My web server is IIS.
sdk tool : SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3
follow the office url 
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/sencha-touch-2.0.1/docs/#!/guide/command

I solved this problem by **executing the cmd as Administrator**..

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/ << your sencha cmd version >>  :$PATH
```

This may solve your problem. Sencha sometimes does not find new Sencha cmd path if it is created on other platforms or if the Sencha folder is created without the use of `generate` command.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Downloaded the latest Sencha SDK and the latest SDK Tools on Windows, got this warning message.

The problem here was that the file `.senchasdk` was missing.

Simple solution: create an empty file called `.senchasdk`

Afterwards everything worked fine.

Comment: After adding the hidden file to the SDK folder it threw an error when I tried to generate an app.