# Sencha touch2 configuration issue.sencha command not found

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, sencha-touch

I m a quite new to phone gap.i m using windows vista 32 bit.I m faceing problem configure sencha touch2 in phone gap.

Download sencha touch sdk and tools from here [link](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/).

When i m trying the command "sencha generate app" in command prompt.I m getting "sencha is not recoznise as command"

Please help .i cant create app unless and until sencha command work on my system.i cant move forword from here.

Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2):

As per Sencha docs possible solutions are:

Upon running sencha, if there is an error message appears saying "sencha: command not found" on OS X / Linux or "'sencha' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." on Windows, follow these steps to troubleshoot:

Close all existing terminal / command prompt windows and re-open them.

Make sure that Sencha SDK Tools is properly installed:
The installation directory exists. By default, the installation path is /Applications/SenchaSDKTools-{version} on OS X, /opt/SenchaSDKTools-{version} on Linux, and C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-{version}

The path to SDK Tools directory is prepended to your system's PATH environment variable. From the terminal, run echo $PATH (echo %PATH% on Windows). The SDK Tools directory should be displayed in part of the output. If this is not the case, add it to your PATH manually.
The environment variable SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_{version} is set, with the value being the absolute path to the installation directory mentioned above. For example: If the installed version is '2.0.0-beta2', a SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 must be set. From the terminal, run echo $SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2 (echo %SENCHA_SDK_TOOLS_2_0_0_BETA2% on Windows). If the output is empty, set the environment variable manually.

Please check **Troubleshooting** heading in below link

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/command

**EDIT:**

Check these answers on SO:

[[WARN] The current working directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\sencha folder) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291742/warn-the-current-working-directory-c-xampp-htdocs-sencha-folder-is-not-a-re?lq=1)

[SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3-windows Command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282455/senchasdktools-2-0-0-beta3-windows-command-not-working)

Comment: installed sdk Tools 2.0.0 Beta 3.Now path commant showing the path of sdk tool like C:\\Program File\senchasdktool-2.0.0-beta-3.

Comment: Thanks..
Now i installed sdk Tools 2.0.0 Beta 3.Now path commant showing the path of sdk tool like C:\\Program File\senchasdktool-2.0.0-beta-3.Now i move to sencha tool directory inside program file and run sencha.It is showing warning like "[WARN] The current working directory (C:\Program Files\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-bet
3) is not a recognized Sencha SDK or application folder. Running in backwards c
mpatible mode." ..Pls help

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed the sencha sdk but not installed the Sencha Cmd

http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download

Go here ... download and install Sencha Cmd